# Calculate weight using distance from point for Weighted Reductions in Earth engine

Tags: google-earth-engine, satellite, atmospheric-correction, composite

I want to calculate the total yearly `NO2` emission from the power plants by using [Sentinel-5p NO2 data](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/datasets/catalog/COPERNICUS_S5P_OFFL_L3_NO2). First I defined my aoi and sum all 365 images into one image using `ee.Reducer.sum()`. After that `reduceRegion` (with `sum reducer`) to find the total yearly sum of no2 of my aoi. But this picks a lot of noise from other emission sources like transport.

For avoiding those, I have planned to use **Weighted Reductions**. I want to use weight in reduceRegion in a way where pixels away from power plants will receive less weight and higher weight to nearest pixels to power plants.

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/reducers_weighting), we can see how to calculate weights for clouds ( the more cloud, the less weight each pixel will get ). But how do I calculate weights in my case where each pixel will receive weights according to distances to nearest power plants.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`ee.FeatureCollection.distance`](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/api_docs#ee.featurecollection.distance) produces an image where pixel values represent the distance to the nearest point. You can convert this image into a linear weight from 0 to 1.

```js
// Mock up a feature collection.
var fc = ee.FeatureCollection([
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-120.831, 37.119])),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-120.193, 37.029])),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-121.119, 36.803])),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-121.130, 36.539])),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-119.872, 36.525])),
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point([-120.432, 36.807]))
]);

// Set maximum distance to consider.
var maxDist = 1e5; // Meters

// Calculate pixel distance to nearest point.
var distance = fc.distance({searchRadius: maxDist, maxError: 10});

// Convert distance to linear weight between 0 and 1.
var weight = distance.subtract(maxDist).abs().divide(maxDist);

// Display the distance and weight images.
Map.centerObject(fc, 9);
Map.addLayer(distance, {min:0, max: maxDist}, 'Meters');
Map.addLayer(weight, {min:0, max: 1}, 'Weight');
Map.addLayer(fc, {color: 'red'}, 'Points');
```

[Code Editor script](https://code.earthengine.google.com/984034dd3bcc38a62ca67536c1169917?as_external)

[image]